# arm-none-eabi-gcc: not found on Windows 10 STM32IDE

Tags: c, ide, cross-compiling

I'm new to coding and working using the STM32IDE. However when I try to cross compile a program (ARM based target program), I keep getting an error saying that "arm-none-eabi-gcc: not found". Is there any way I can fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: arm-none-eabi-gcc is the name of the cross-compiler itself. You will need to install it. Unfortunately, I don't know the Windows 10 STM32IDE, or where you can obtain the compiler.

Comment: Did you check that you have that compiler installed? If so, does the STM32IDE need the PATH environment variable be extended with the compiler's path?

Comment: It says on the website that it is supposed to be installed (https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stm32cubeide.html). However I dont know how to find if the compiler is installed or not. Is there a way to check?

Answer (score 0):

I had to find the cross-compiler online and install it manually. If anyone else has this problem the one I used can be found here: https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/open-source-software/developer-tools/gnu-toolchain/gnu-rm/downloads?fbclid=IwAR3WpgNJaqNSo0Y7G4RxPfz1g0WgGFYv8BHzFK0YvY1rw8964uTTfLkma5o